# Check whether the email is a reply or response with Python win32com

Tags: python, email, outlook

I am using Python win32com to parse email from outlook . I am able to fetch email from the outlook folder , but I not able to verify whether the email is a reply or response or a forwarded message , I need to check whether the email reiceved is the reply of the previous mail (if yes then find the original mail) or email is the forwarded message. I am using following code to fetch emails from outlook.

```
import win32com.client 

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox=outlook.Folders['xyz@xyz.com'].Folders['Inbox'].Folders['abc']
messagesReach = inbox.Items
for message in messagesReach:
    if message.Unread==True:
       print(message.body)
```

Comment: Look for the `In-Reply-To` header.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it is showing attribute error

Comment: I guess you're not looking for the header in the proper way.

Comment: Got the answer , the header is `ConversationID` and this will work like `message.ConversationID`. Thanks for your help @Barmar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi the header is `ConversationID` and can be used as `message.ConversationID`
refer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mailitem_properties.aspx

Comment: Can you accept your answer, so people who find this question can see the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to read the first three characters of the subject, and determine if it has the "Re:"-prefix and therefore is a reply. This should be the case most times.

```
import win32com.client 

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.Folders["xyz@xyz.com"].Folders["Inbox"].Folders["abc"]
messagesReach = inbox.Items
for message in messagesReach:
    if message.Unread == True:
       if message.Subject[:3] == "Re:":
          print(message.body)
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply, we can so but with it we can not find the original mail and also if the sender doesn't mention "RE:" in subject then this will fail

Comment: That's correct, but I didn't find another way. There's no property of `message` that says if it's a reply or a response. Not even in the [property list][1] of `Mailitem` is a property that could give that information.

[https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mailitem_properties.aspx][1]

Comment: Basically I need to find the e-mail chain, in laymen's language I want to read replies of previous e-mail like a conversation for example I sent a mail to somebody for approval of something the as a reply I got the email stating approve , then I need to find the original mail on which the approval is given.

Comment: Got the answer , the header is `ConversationID` and this will work like `message.ConversationID`. Thanks for your help @Markus Schwer